# Ember Data not sending to server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code:

app/models/account.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  birthdate: DS.attr('date'),
  gender: DS.attr('boolean'),
  emailaddresses: DS.attr()
});
```

and app/components/account-profile.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  buttonLabel: 'Send to Server',
  actions: {
    buttonClicked(param) {
      this.sendAction('action', param);
    }
  }
});
```

and app/templates/components/account-profile.hbs

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">Your Profile</div>
  <div>Username: {{account.accountprofile.username}}</div>
  <div>Email Address: {{account.accountprofile.emailaddresses.0.emailaddress}}</div>
  <div>Birthdate: {{account.accountprofile.birthdate}}</div>
  <div>Gender: {{account.accountprofile.gender}}</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div>
      {{input type="text" value=account.accountprofile.username }}
    </div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div>
      {{input type="text" value=account.accountprofile.emailaddresses.0.emailaddress }}
    </div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div>
      {{input type="text" value=account.accountprofile.birthdate }}
    </div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div>
      {{input type="text" value=account.accountprofile.gender }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" {{action 'buttonClicked' account}}>{{buttonLabel}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not see any traffic being sent from from my web browser to my server.

What is missing and what's wrong with my code? What other things I need to do?

Comment: Note that emailaddress is missing from the input forms, and that the field names are wrong. That's not important. I am just trying to get Ember Data to send to server (via POST or PUT) working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Persisting Records](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_persisting-records) in ember guides

> Records in Ember Data are persisted on a per-instance basis. Call
>   save() on any instance of DS.Model and it will make a network request.

You need to call `save` method from the record `account.accountprofile` like this `this.get('account.accountprofile').save()`

Comment: I changed to "this.get('account.accountprofile').save();" and indeed Ember Data is sending a PUT request to the server. However, there's nothing in the request on the server side. How does Ember Data send the data in the request?

Comment: I also did make sure that I "dirty" the data by changing the values. Again, I do see the request received on the server, but cannot find the data.

Comment: I am not much familiar with ember-data . In your case PUT request will be called and you will get `account` object in request.
Adapter is responsible for sending request to server, so have a look at your adapter's overriden method. refer [`updateRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_updateRecord)

Answer (score -1):

sendAction does not send something to the server.

See https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

So try param.save() to save your model for example.

Comment: I replaced that with param.save() and it says "Uncaught TypeError: param.save is not a function". Where do I insert param.save()?

Comment: I think you're missing some basics in ember programming. you should do the guids on https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/

If params.save is not a function then account/params ist not a ember-data model